# swaping value in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say i have array like

```
var x = [{
      value: 10,
      age: 20,
  }, {
      value: 9,
      age: 19,
  }, {
      value: 8,
      age: 18,
  }];
```

how can i change to array to look like this

```
  var x = [{
      value: 11,
      age: 21,
  }, {
      value: 10,
      age: 20,
  }, {
      value: 9,
      age: 19,
  }];
```

in the most effective way without manualy rewriting values? basicly to to increment first values and then change value of the next indexed element to previous value? Basicly

```
var g=[1st value,2nd value,3rd value] => [incremented first value,first value,second value]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.unshift` + `Array.prototype.pop`

Comment: `x.unshift((function(){ var y = x.pop(); y.value = x[0].value+1; y.age = x[0].age+1; return y; })());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var x = [{
        value: 10,
        age: 20,
    }, {
        value: 9,
        age: 19,
    }, {
        value: 8,
        age: 18,
    }];
var newX = x.map(function (obj){
    var newObj = {};

    var newValue = obj.value + 1;
    var newAge = obj.age + 1;
    newObj["value"] = newValue;
    newObj["age"] = newAge;
    return newObj;
})
console.log(newX);
```

Comment: what if its not just +1 increment? What if i want only increment first element in array , and then want the second element to be egual to first element before increment and so on

Answer (score -1):

A simple `for loop` is enough to solve your problem and will be one of the more efficient ways also according to [this](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-jquery-each/59). (definitely more efficient than `$.each` and `Array.prototype.forEach`)

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].value += 1;
    x[i].age += 1;
}
```